# Vue + Spring boot,unable to get the authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, vuejs3

The provided configuration works for Google, and I can obtain authentication in the sixth step, such as Name: [114139398535802188369], Granted Authorities, and so on. However, when using Facebook, I am unable to print anything, and the result in the Vue console is an AxiosError. Please help me with this issue.

Vue

```
  getFBStatus() {
            const FB = this.$store.state.FB
            FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    const code = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    this.sendCodeToBackend('facebook', code)
                }
            })
        },
        sendCodeToBackend(name, code) {
            this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8081/api/oauth/' + name, this.socialLoginForm, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            })
                .then(response => {
                    this.loginResponseProcessiing(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/api/oauth/facebook")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> facebookTest(@RequestBody SocialLoginRequest socialLoginRequest,HttpServletRequest request) {
    LoginResponse res = socialLoginTokenService.createToken(socialLoginRequest,request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(res);
    }
```

SocialLoginTokenService

```
public LoginResponse createToken(SocialLoginRequest socialLoginRequest,HttpServletRequest request) {
        String readCode = socialLoginRequest.getCode();
        
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = createGoogleClientRegistration(socialLoginRequest);

        String clientName = clientRegistration.getClientName();

        //1.resolver 
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository, "/auth");
        //2.request 
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request, clientName);
        //3.response
        OAuth2AuthorizationResponse authorizationResponse = OAuth2AuthorizationResponse
                .success(readCode)
                .code(readCode)
                .redirectUri("postmessage") 
                .state(authorizationRequest.getState())
                .build();
        // 4. authentication
        Authentication authentication = new OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken(
                clientRegistration, new OAuth2AuthorizationExchange(authorizationRequest, authorizationResponse));

        // 5. authenticationProvider 
        OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider  = new OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider(tokenResponseClient, userService);
                // 6. authenticate
        authentication = authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
                System.out.println(authentication);
        //7. get useretails
        DefaultOAuth2User userDetails =(DefaultOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Oauth2Config

```
private ClientRegistration facebookClientRegistration() {
    
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("Facebook")
                .clientId("my id")
                .clientSecret("my secret")
                .redirectUri("postmessage")
                .authorizationUri("https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth") 
                .tokenUri("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .scope("email","public_profile")
                .userInfoUri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday,gender,location")
                .clientName("Facebook")
                .userNameAttributeName("id")
                .build();
    }
```

I have confirmed that the accessToken, id, and secret are correct, so I'm not sure which part of the process is encountering an issue.

Comment: Show your request and response with headers. Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Comment: I found in the debug log the message 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Invalid verification code format.' The code I passed in is obtained from FB.getLoginStatus, perhaps the access token is not equivalent to the authentication code?

Comment: I initially misunderstood and used the access token instead of the authentication code. I used 「https://www.facebook.com/v12.0/dialog/oauth
    ?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
    &scope=email,user_posts
    &response_type=code」 to get the authentication code and sent it to the backend. Finally I got the authentication .Thanks for providing the guidance that led to the solution.